# Error:Segmentation fault(code dump)

Tags: c, data-structures

I am new to data structures and started with linked list where i tried to add element at the end of the linked list but getting an error segmentation fault .
I am implementing it in C language.

I don't understand what this error means

**CODE:**

```
struct node 
{
int data;
struct node *next;
};
struct node *head;
void fnInsert(int x){
    if(head==NULL){
    printf("head is null");
    node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=x;
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
    }
    else{
        node* temp=head;
        struct node* previousNode;
        do{
            temp=temp->next;
            previousNode=temp;
        }while(temp!=NULL);
        node* temp1=(node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp1->data=x;
            previousNode->next=temp1;
            temp1->next=NULL;
    }
};
void fnPrint(){
   struct node* temp=head;
   printf("list is:\n");
   while(temp!=NULL){
       printf("%d",temp->data);
       temp=temp->next;
       printf("\n");
   }
}
int main(){
    head=NULL;
    printf("how many numbers\n");
    int n,i,x;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Enter the number\n");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        fnInsert(x);
        fnPrint();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Segmentation fault means the code accessed invalid memory. Use a debugger to help you find the problem.

Comment: @kaylum
I am doing it online so there is no option to debug :(

Comment: Do you have a home PC? Many debuggers can be downloaded for free.

Comment: I don't execute your code, but here 
            "temp=temp->next;
            previousNode=temp;"
 I think you are doing it in the inverse order. temp->next is probably NULL, so previousNode will be null, and of course, previousNode->next doesn't exist.

Comment: hey @Alexi

Thanks for the info.

It worked for me:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in these lines:

```
temp=temp->next;
previousNode=temp;
```

It should be opposite i.e

```
previousNode=temp;
temp=temp->next;
```

In your case `previousNode` is eventually becoming `NULL` and you are trying to access `previousNode->next` i.e Dereference a `NULL` pointer. So it is a segmentation fault.

Also you have used `node*` in many places. You should replace all of them with `struct node*` or you can `typedef`